# Set MIME type for http-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mime-types, cesiumjs

I am using Cesium Terrain Provider. it requires that the MIME type returned by the server be 'application/octet-stream'. I am currently serving directory using http-server available through npm. How do i configure the server to do so? Is there any other better alternative ?

Comment: hi, have you seen this >>> https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-http-server

Comment: It doesn't work. I am trying to share a directory with a specific MIME type to be returned by the server. Is there any option in node or should I go for Apache?

Comment: I dont know Node as Much, but i Found something by Googling.
See this >> https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=share+dir+with+MIME+Type+in+Node
<<<< May this Help You.

Answer (score 0):

The Cesium terrain provider is more or less intended to be used with the STK Terrain Server.  Take a look at the GeoServer terrain provider and see if that will work better for your current server config

Comment: GeoServer won't be possible. I need something that uses far less resources. That's why node would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was:

```
import http.server
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import socketserver

PORT = 8080

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Handler.extensions_map={
        '.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',
    '.html': 'text/html',
        '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.js':  'application/x-javascript',
    '': 'application/octet-stream', # Default
    }

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Put it in a .py file in the folder of your index.html and start it with `python example.py`. [Source](https://gist.github.com/HaiyangXu/ec88cbdce3cdbac7b8d5).

The error that I was getting is that my js was interpreted as 'text/plain'